# Expandable floating action button that is docked in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I want to create a center docked floating action bar button that is expandable. The current design of the expandable floating action button is as shown

[image]

The floating action button is a column of transform widgets that expands/collapses when the bottom toggle button is pressed. The floating action button is center docked, and has a shape of CircularNotchedRectangle, with a notchMargin of 10. However, this method produces an unwanted background (the shape behind the buttons) when collapsed and expanded. I want it to be able to look like this.

[image]

How would I attempt at solving this problem.

The code for the floating action button is shown below

```
floatingActionButton: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Transform(
              transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                  0.0, _translateButton!.value * 3.0, 0.0),
              child: buttonAdd()),
          Transform(
            transform: Matrix4.translationValues(
                0.0, _translateButton!.value * 2.0, 0.0),
            child: buttonFile(),
          ),
          Transform(
            transform:
                Matrix4.translationValues(0.0, _translateButton!.value, 0.0),
            child: buttonFolder(),
          ),
          buttonToggle(),
          SizedBox(height: 30),
        ],
      ),
```

and the code for the button navigation bar

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          color: default_background_color,
          notchMargin: 10,
          child: Container(
            height: 60,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.blue),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    MaterialButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Icon(Icons.settings, color: Colors.blue),
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom FAB is taller than a normal FAB because it has additional items. Trying to fit this as a docked item does not work well.

**This tutorial solved this issue for me.**
https://codewithandrea.com/articles/adding-animated-overlays-to-your-app/

He solves this issue by using [Overlays](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html).